# Populate a JSON file with Rails fields in Profile.all

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, json, jquery-tokeninput

I'm using jQuery Tokeninput for `tags` in my Rails app. I have never dealt with JSON before (I'm new to programming) but I was wondering if there was a way to create then populate a json file with string values from `Profile.all`.

Here is the `index` in my `TagsController`:

```
class TagsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @tags = Tag.where("name like ?", "%#{params[:q]}%")
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json { render :json => @tags.map(&:attributes) }
    end
  end
end
```

If it is possible, can someone give me an idea of how it might be done? If more code is needed let me know!

**EXPLANATION:** The reason I want to do this is to limit `@tags` to tags that already exist.

Answer (score 0):

So, if I understand correctly, the code you posted works correctly? But now you don't want to stream the JSON output to the browser, but write it to a file?

Take a look at how Rails renders JSON in [the source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/responder.rb). It's pretty straightforward, it simply calls the `to_json` function on any object that is being rendered.

Also take a look at [this excellent post](http://yehudakatz.com/2010/01/10/activemodel-make-any-ruby-object-feel-like-activerecord/) by Yehuda Katz. Look up the section for *Serialization*.

Now, to save all your Profile models as JSON to a file, you can do something like this:

```
File.open("all_profiles.json", "w") { |f| f.write(Profile.all.to_json) }
```

---

**Edit**:

With your added explanation, here's some more info:

JSON of certain fields in your models:

```
Profile.all.collect { |p| { :name => p.name, :city => p.city } }.to_json
```

This would give you an array like this in Ruby:

```
[ {:name = "John", :city => "Liverpool"}, {:name = "Jimi", :city => "Seattle"} ]
```

And JSON like this:

```
[ {"name":"John", "city":"Liverpool"}, {"name":"Jimi", "city":"Seattle"} ]
```

Comment: it's a good idea to keep json cached in public directory. Looks very good

Comment: I hope this will make sense, but what I want is for my autocomplete to only provide certain fields from my Profile model as options. For example, `:name` wouldn't be an option but say `:city` would. So I'm curious how to create JSON output from specific parts of the Profile.